# MonoTouch.Dialog: Enabling ScopeButton on Search removes search events

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm not sure if this is a bug.

In MonoTouch.Dialog enable the ScopeButton and wire up the Index Change event:

```
        UISearchBar sb = TableView.TableHeaderView as UISearchBar;
        sb.ScopeButtonTitles = new string[] { "Full Text".t(), "Titles".t() };
        sb.ShowsScopeBar = true;
        sb.SizeToFit();
        sb.SelectedScopeButtonIndexChanged += (sender, e) => {
            CreateRoot(sb.Text);
        };
```

Then over ride the Search Functions:

```
    public override void FinishSearch()
    {
        //do nothing, leave the UI 
    }

    public override void OnSearchTextChanged(string text)
    {
        CreateRoot(text);
    }

    public override void SearchButtonClicked(string text)
    {
         //Do nothing, leave the UI
    }
```

The result is that the OnSearchTextChanged never fires.

If you remove the follow lines, it fires and works just fine.

```
//Remove to re-enable SearchButtonClicked
sb.SelectedScopeButtonIndexChanged += (sender, e) => {
CreateRoot(sb.Text);
};
```

NOTE: If you access the SearchBar's UISegment Control via the SubViews, it works fine that way

```
    foreach (UIView v in sb.Subviews)
    {
        var seg = v as UISegmentedControl;
        if(seg!=null)
        {
            CreateRoot("Some text");
        };
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I've just noticed the exact same thing. My search brought me here :)

Comment: Get the newest MT.D, it's fixed there

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the newest build of MOnotouch.dialog